# How to activate Pinch-To-Zoom/Twisting with Synaptics Touchpad?

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch

Where do I find those features? In Ubuntu there's only an option to enable Two-Finger-Scrolling.

Greetz.

Comment: Thanks user 25656 and spacemonkeyPDX..both of these worked for me.
I must say the CTRL+2 finger scroll is more convenient. Thanks once again guys...

Answer (score 33):

Holding down <kbd>CTRL</kbd> while pinching or zooming will allow you to perform the gesture.

Comment: @Bakly is right. AFAIK Ubuntu out of the box is oblivious to the pinch gesture. And the documentation is silent about it as well...

Comment: Is there a way to activate this without having to hold ctrl?

Comment: I will make a new question for asking how to make this without holding the ctrl

Comment: This does not work on Ubuntu 18.04 in Chrome 84.0.4147.89

Comment: Does not work on Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 23):

@SpaceMonkeyPDX

Its not the real pinch to zoom gesture as expected. Its <kbd>scrollUp</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  zooms in ,<kbd>scrollDown</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  zooms out.

and because you have the `Two-Finger-Scrolling` enabled it seems like it but the right gesture is to scrollup and down with your two fingers while pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> button

Comment: Thats not a gesture, this is just normal behaviour. Zoom was always `ctrl` + `scroll`

Comment: `Ctrl` + `Pinch` works as well, so it is a real pinch.

Comment: @ЕлинЙ. at the time of your answer sure, but at the time this was answered pinch was not supported yet

Comment: @ЕлинЙ. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Pinch</kbd> doesn't work here, Ubuntu 20.10. Ctrl+Scroll does

Answer (score 5):

I know it is a bit late but for others who may drop by

Type ***synclient***  to list all touchpad features then create a file to execute them at startup.

For example on 12.10 I am using these lines in my script:

```
synclient TapButton2=2
synclient TapButton3=3
synclient HorizEdgeScroll=1
synclient HorizTwoFingerScroll=1
synclient CircularScrolling=1
synclient PalmDetect=1
```

These enable Horizontal edge, two finger horizontal scroll, middle mouse button by tapping with two fingers and right mouse button by tapping with three fingers and palm detection to avoid unwanted clicks while typing...

But for pinch zoom. It seems there is nothing available at the moment.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question

Comment: @asymptotically did you try?

Comment: The OP wanted to know how to enable pinch to zoom and twisting. And yes, I have used synclient before, and it doesn't have an option to allow pinch to zoom.

Comment: @asymptotically then I edited my question. last paragraph

Comment: Well, you added that just yesterday.

Comment: @asymptotically Yeap, you are right.

Comment: @wakeup thanks for this answer. it gives me a hell lot of more control on my touchpad and system than ever before. Instead of creating a script I added to my bashrc. Pretty cool! Thanks again!

Comment: In my Ubuntu 19.10 these settings are in `~/.xprofile`

Answer (score 4):

Friends, I am on Ubuntu 21.04 now. And two-fingures-pinch-zoom works out of the box with Firefox.
Real pinch zoom mac-style. Not just page scaling CTRL+[+], which makes responsive pages to change layout to mobile. But real useful zoom. which I use a lot when viewing images and sometimes paragraphs.

Answer (score 3):

I had success using [Fusuma](https://github.com/iberianpig/fusuma) and xdotool. Install xdotool and the Fusuma gem and then create its config file at `~/.config/fusuma/config.yml` and include the following:

```
pinch:
      2:
        in:
          command: 'xdotool key ctrl+plus'
          threshold: 0.15
        out:
          command: 'xdotool key ctrl+minus'
          threshold: 0.15
```

You may have to fiddle with the threshold and interval values until it responds to your liking.

Comment: I tried it but it is not smooth at all

Answer (score -1):

Some multi-touch features can be activated with the instructions here (at least on hp dv9000, not sure about other laptops)
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1999255

Comment: In those instructions there is no pinching gesture...

Answer (score -1):

Working for me, finded this solutoin today. Install **gnome tweaks** -> open it -> go to kyboard & mouse: find section "**mouse click emulation**" and choose "Area"
After this I can **pinch to zoom** on my touchpad in google chrome browser.