# Activate pinch to zoom in Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, dell, multi-touch

I know this question has been asked before, but most questions with answers seem outdated (like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111510/how-to-activate-pinch-to-zoom-twisting-with-synaptics-touchpad)) and I was wondering if anything has changed.

In Ubuntu 16.04 (Unity), is it possible to have pinch-to-zoom gestures on a touchpad, provided that the hardware allows it? I have a Dell XPS 13 (which shipped with 14.04, but I upgraded it) and the touchpad allows two-finger scrolling just fine, but I do miss the more fancy multi-touch functionalities. [This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33574/how-can-i-test-to-see-if-my-touchpad-is-supports-more-than-2-finger-gestures) explains how to check the number of fingers the touchpad supports using the `geis-tools` package; I found my laptop actually detects five, so it should be possible in principle. *Off-topic: Who even uses five-finger gestures?*

Answer (score 4):

Holding down CTRL while pinching or zooming will allow you to perform the gesture.

From [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111510/how-to-activate-pinch-to-zoom-twisting-with-synaptics-touchpad#answer-260152) post

Comment: Thanks! I had eventually figured this out myself too. It works fine, although unfortunately having to use the CTRL key makes it slightly less intuitive and well-designed than the functionality in Windows or iOS.