# How to zoom in on screen using the touchpad?

Tags: google-chrome, touchpad, zooming

I just started using Ubuntu. I really liked how I could just zoom in on any point on the screen using the touchpad in macOS. It worked in certain places like chrome or safari. I want to know if there is a way of doing that in Ubuntu as well. I know how I can zoom in on a page but I want to zoom in on the screen using touchpad in chrome. Kind of like a magnifying glass.

Comment: Possible:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/111510/how-to-activate-pinch-to-zoom-twisting-with-synaptics-touchpad

Comment: @Terrance I don't think that's the same as it zooms in the page. I want to instead zoom in on the screen without changing page zoom.

Comment: The only one you can try that is built in is go to Settings -> Universal Access then enable Zoom.  But it is either on or off that I can see and I can't see if you can enable a keyboard / mouse shortcut for it.  https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/a11y-mag.html.en

Answer (score 0):

works for me in Wayland

```
google-chrome-stable --enable-features=UseOzonePlatform --ozone-platform=wayland
```